# Override theme brush Windows 10 UWP

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm trying to override some style-colors in Windows 10 but I cannot get it to work.

My app.xaml looks like this:

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default" Source="Theme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And my Theme.xaml looks like this

```
<ResourceDictionary
x:Key="Default"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarButtonForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarPanningBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="White"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SearchBoxHitHighlightSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SearchBoxHitHighlightForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Pink"/>
```

However it doesn't work, it doesn't override the style anywhere.

Comment: The "Default" key is related to Dark theme, try adding a new line with "Light" key. Also take care with the differences between StaticResource and ThemeResource.

Answer (score 7):

The styles you are setting are for Windows 8 apps. The styles used by Universal Windows apps are greatly simplified.

The easiest way to find them is to add your ListBox to a page, right click on it in the designer, and select Edit Template... Create a copy of the template and look at the names used.

All of the controls now use the same brushes when possible rather than having control-specific ones.

For example, the ListBox uses the following brushes for its Foreground, Background, and BorderBrush:

- SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush
- SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush
- SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush

Comment: Actually that is what I did. The overriden SearchBox style is: http://pastebin.com/39aG751n yet it doesn't work to change some colors such as SearchBoxHitHighlightForegroundThemeBrush and SearchBoxHitHighlightSelectedForegroundThemeBrush

Comment: This worked for me in the RTM version of Windows 10 IoT / UWP. For example to override the annoying pink default accent brush and put your brand colour there: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource YourBrandColorResourceKey}" />

Answer (score 4):

To add to Rob's answer, for those looking for a broader app-wide response, it helped me to find the full default themes, which are available in 
`\(Program Files)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\<SDK version>\Generic folder` of a Windows SDK installation, in themeresources.xaml.

In that is a ResourceDictionary for Default, HighContrast, and Light. The default key handles the Dark theme in UWP, since it is what will be defaulted to when no default "Dark" ResourceDictionary is found.

**The Default and Light** themes have nearly 1000 control-specific colors, or more generic "SystemControlForeground..." colors like Rob showed, but in UWP they are mostly based on the following 25 color categories:

- [24 system colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Laa.png)
- `SystemAccentColor`, an OS-wide user-defined color which the UWP docs has a whole page about under Design & UI > Style > Color

  - There's 6 lighter and darker shades of the above (`SystemAccentColorLight1`, `...Dark1`, etc) but they aren't used in the default resource dictionaries. However .6, .8 and .9 opacities of that color are used a handful of times, the only time opacities are used.

Then there are the 300+ color categories from Windows 8.1 that are left in, which manually pick a specific color, the extent of which you can see [here](http://metro.excastle.com/xaml-system-brushes)

The only exception to the above is that the InkToolBar styling is almost exclusively derived from the High Contrast colors.

**The High Contrast** theme, pulls heavily from 8 additional System[blank]Colors that, similar to the `SystemAccentColor`, are OS-wide values. They're defined by templates and/or the user if they chose a High Contrast theme, which is an option Windows 10 has in its personalization settings. High Contrast is also an accessibility feature, so I think I'll be avoiding overriding that ResourceDictionary, no matter the app branding.

But effectively, by overriding the `SystemAccentColor` and the 24 System[blank]Colors in the XAML framework, you can effect the change of hundreds of specific color choices in a consistent way across an app.