# System resource not found in UWP app

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm joining a UWP app already in development that uses the `HyperlinkButtonBorderBrush` system resource, but I'm getting a `ResourceNotFoundException` when running the app.  (It runs fine on other devs' machines.)

Just to make sure, I created a new UWP app and set the background to `{ThemeResource HyperlinkButtonBorderBrush}`.  This also produces the error, so I know the issue is my machine.

I've verified that I have all of the theme files from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751974/878701), and the files contain the resource.

I'm running VS2017 (15.2) on Win10 (1511, build 10586.916).  I'll provide any additional information as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HyperlinkButtonBorderBrush` was added in Windows 10 Anniversary Update (*14393*), but the build you are running is one version older.

I guess your colleagues are all using at least *14393*, and I don't think you can find this resource inside the `10.0.10586.0` folder, it first appeared in the `10.0.14393.0` folder.

I'd suggest to either not use this resource or increase the minimum support of your app to `14393`.

Comment: It doesn't matter, when your system is *10586*, it will use the *10.0.10586.0* folder, if any of your users are with *10586*, the app will crash on startup.

Comment: I figured as much about the users.  Thanks.